# regex to match a fixed char sequence followed by an uppercase alphabet

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am working in eclispe and have a bean class in which all the variables are prefixed by a fixed char sequence.

```
public class Foo{

  private barName;
  private barCity;
  private barCountry;

  // getters and setters

}
```

I can do a find and replace (`bar` with `''`) but that will leave all variables name capitalized. Since find and replace in eclipse support regular expressions, how can I remove bar and get the variable name start with lowercase in one go?

Comment: try this expression \syourPrefix[A-Z]*.;

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
\sbar[A-Z]*.;
```

`\s` for space (maybe change to whitespace)
`bar` is fixed
`[A-Z]` for 1 upper case letter
`*.` for anything that follows
`;` for end of expression

Comment: This does the matching but what to put in replace expression?